# Struggling to transfer a doubly linked generic list to circular. (segfault)

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

So I've got this non-circular doubly linked list sample and I find it rather hard to transfer it to a circular one. (segfaulting on the //added lines)
Any advise would be nice.
Thanks in advance.
Also, should I use overloading to handle input of different types? How do I manipulate them? A link with a proper example (really couldn't find one) would make me happy.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dlring.cpp"
int main()
{
    dlring<int> dlist;
    dlist.Append( 11 );
    dlist.Push( 100 );
    while(dlist)
    std::cout << dlist.pop_back()  << " ";

}
```

dlring.h

```
           template <typename T>
        class dlring
        {
            struct node
            {
                T data;
                node* prev;
                node* next;
                node(T t, node* p, node* n) : data(t), prev(p), next(n) {}
            };
            node* head;
            node* tail;
        public:
            dlring() : head(nullptr), tail (nullptr) {}
            bool empty() const { return ( !head || !tail ); }
            operator bool() const { return !empty(); }
//Yes, I also wish to implement this bool stuff otherwise.
            void Append(T);
            void Push(T);
            T pop_back();
            T pop_front();
            ~dlring()
            {
                while(head)
                {
                    node* temp(head);
                    head=head->next;
                    delete temp;
                }
            }
        };
```

dlring.cpp

```
#include "dlring.h"
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
void dlring<T>::Append(T data)
{
    tail = new node(data, tail, head); //changed NULL=>head
    if( tail->prev )
    {
        tail->prev->next = tail;
        head->prev = tail; //added
    }
    if( empty() )
        head = tail;
}
template <typename T>
void dlring<T>::Push(T data)
{
    head = new node(data, tail, head);   //changed NULL=>tail
    if( head->next )
    {
        head->next->prev = head;
        tail->next = head; //added
    }
    if( empty() )
        tail = head;
}
template<typename T>
T dlring<T>::pop_back()
{
    if( empty() )
        std::cout<<"List empty";
    node* temp(tail);
    T data( tail->data );
    tail = tail->prev ;
    if( tail )
    {
        tail->next = head; //null=>head;
        head->prev = tail; //added
    }
    else
        head = nullptr; //NULL=>nullptr
    delete temp;
    return data;
}
template<typename T>
T dlring<T>::pop_front()
{
    if( empty() )
        std::cout<<"List empty";
    node* temp(head);
    T data( head->data );
    head = head->next ;
    if( head )
    {
        head->prev = tail; //NULL=>nullptr=>tail
        tail->next = head;
    }
    else
        tail = nullptr; //NULL=>nullptr
    delete temp;
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is in the `pop_back` function:

```
node * temp(tail);
T data(tail->data);
tail = tail->prev;

if(tail)
{
    tail->next = head; //null=>head;
    head->prev = tail; //added
}
else
{
    head = nullptr; //NULL=>nullptr
}

delete temp;
```

When there is only one node in the list, `tail` isn't `null` - this means the `if` condition will be met, and the code below will be hit:

```
tail->next = head; //null=>head;
head->prev = tail; //added
```

But this code does nothing, because `tail` and `head` are the same thing.  You then delete the only node in the list, and `head` and `tail` no longer point to anything.  To solve this, you need a better way to detect if the list will be empty after deletion, and to alter the deletion code a bit:

```
if (tail != temp)
{
    tail->next = head; //null=>head;
    head->prev = tail; //added
}
else
{
    head = nullptr; //NULL=>nullptr
    tail = nullptr;
}

delete temp;
temp = nullptr;
```

Comment: Brilliant, yet simple! Thanks a ton, sad I can't vote this up.
Should I get rid of the bool empty() by implementing the check in a better way, like nullptr check?

UPD: Going to continue the work and leave here a working imlementation via editing the post.

Comment: Don't edit the question, accept this post as the answer instead.

Comment: @ГлушковМакс do what user4581301 said.  If this solved your problem, you should accept the answer and ask a new question instead of editing the current question.  Also, I don't really see a better way to check for empty, really.  You could keep track of the size or add a dummy node that is always the tail and head, but that might be a bit of work.

Comment: @dwcanillas Done, shall think about the dummy node implementation. Best regards.